# js.erb rendered into layout, not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm attempting to update a span using a simple link_to and an action. Visually when I click the link 'nothing happens', (the page doesn't change).

Looking at the response to the request, I see my layout with the contents of the js.erb file inserted where the layout yields.

My environment is Rails 4.2 running under Docker on OS X and also Elastic Beanstalk on AWS.

```
app/views/admin/games.haml:
%p=link_to("Hint please", {:action=> "hint"}, :remote => true)

%span#hint
  where next?
```

app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:

```
  def hint
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

app/views/admin/hint.js.erb:

```
$("#hint").text('hello coffee');
```

rails log on clicking the link:

```
Started GET "/admin/hint" for 192.168.99.1 at 2016-03-14 12:04:33 +0000
Cannot render console from 192.168.99.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminController#hint as JS
    Rendered admin/hint.js.erb within layouts/admin (0.0ms)
    Rendered application/_favicon.haml (8.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 197ms (Views: 196.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I followed the debug instructions at https://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/ - I see no Javascript errors. The response is the layout with the contents of the .js.erb rendered as text where the yield command is in the layout:

```
<div id='main'>
    <div class='header'>
        <h1></h1>
        <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        $("#hint").text('hello coffee');
    </div>
</div>
```

This is driving me crazy, thank you for your help.

Comment: just remove respond_to from you hint method. No need for redirect,render and respond.

Comment: @prashu thanks for your comment. This didn't help. BoraMa's answer below solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you suffer from [Rails bug/feature #10768](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10768)?

I.e., such behavior occurs if your main layout is called `application.haml` instead of `application.html.haml`. it is because layouts without a format extension are rendered for all formats by default.

I can see you are using HAML, so am guessing this might be it.

Comment: That's it, thank you. I find if I rename all of the following: application.haml -> application.html.haml, the layout for the specific controller admin.haml -> admin.html.haml, and the actions view games.haml -> games.html.ham - it works on first click. (It doesn't work unless I rename application.haml too).

I can see now the demo app at https://github.com/mohitjain/ajaxified_scaffold/tree/master/app uses similar filename structure.

I also manage a Rails 2 app that, it uses just a plain .haml extension successfully so that's partly how I came down this path I guess.

Thanks again.